# capture oracles's (sequence.nexval) value in a column during data flow

Tags: ssis

I am doing an insert from SQL server table to Oracle table, which has a sequence for its identity column. I have used OLDDB command as my destination and used the following query for insert into oracle table

```
Insert into tablename (id, col1,col2....) values (seq.nextval,?,?,...)
```

I mapped all parameters to source columns and it works like a charm including sequence generation for identity column.

My other requirement is that the sequence that was generated in the first table has to be mapped with another table for foreign key relation, as follows:

```
table 1

emp table with columns 
empid ----------- generated from sequence
name suffix

table 2

empinfo table with column
empinfoid ---- generated from sequence 
empid ----- id that was generated in table 1. 
address
edulevel
```

Since I do not have any others common keys between these two tables, I cannot have lookup and pull empid from table 1 to table 2.

How can I insert empid (generated from sequence) into both tables in parallel? I tried with oledb command out parameter, but wasn't successful as the Oracle connection is unable to find output params.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you run both insert statements are in the same session, you insert `seq.currval` in table2.